# DateIF and countif? Excel formula

Tags: excel, formula, countif, time-frequency

I have a list of IDs that have multiple dates and I am trying to count the months for each specific eeid to calculate a timeframe how long someone is on medication.

So far, I did a countif(A:A,A) showing how many times the eeid shows up but now I am figuring out how to add in the months.

Example:

```
EEID DATE        count of months? 
1234 1/2/20               5
1234 5/2/20               5
1234 6/2/20               5
2222 5/6/21               3
2222 8/6/21               3
9876 3/2/22               0
5555 12/2/21              6
5555 1/2/22               6
5555 3/2/22               6
5555 5/2/22               6
```

Thank you!

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: one hint: you are not trying to count the months but figure the number of months between the max date of that eeid and the minimum date of that eeid.

Comment: =MAX(IF(G:G=G2,J:J))-MIN(IF(G:G=G2,J:J))    - G would be the eeid and J would be either the max or min date; now what i have is a date.... i think

Comment: `=INT((MAX(IF(G:G=G2,J:J))-MIN(IF(G:G=G2,J:J)))/30)`